# Sort by group, then count he number of records

Tags: r, group-by, count

Im trying to do something that I think is supposed simple, but I keep confusing different functions.

I have three columns in my df:

```
 state ID  service
 1    2     1  
 1    7     2  
 4    7     3  
 5    6     4  
 4    6     5  
 5    4     6  
 6    4     7
```

And I need to figure out 1) the number of service per ID and 2)the number of  (service per ID) per state

From other threads on here, I've been able to come up with the following code:

```
 a<- df %>% count(ID)
```

to give me the number of service per ID - so this was successful

Now I need this number by state and tried:

```
 a<- df %>% count(state,ID) or
 a<- df %>% group_by (state) %>% count(ID)
```

I though this would be easy, but can't seem to get my head around it. The df I am working with is very large, But my end output would be:

```
 state count
 1       23    
 2       18 
 3       34
 4       25
 5       10
 6       25
 7       76
```

where df$count is the average number of service per ID per state

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: yep! Ill edit the post

Comment: Do you need `df %>% add_count(ID, name = 'n1') %>% add_count(state, ID, name = 'n2')`

Comment: the count 23, 18, etc is not correlated with your input data

Comment: I wasn't sure how to show a summary from the large dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description, perhaps get the frequency of observations grouped by 'state', 'ID' in `summarise`, then do a `summarise` again to get the `mean` of that count column 'n'

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~state, ~ID,  ~service,
  1,      2,    1,
  1,      7,    2,
  4,      7,    3,
  5,      6,    4,
  4,      6,    5,
  5,      4,    6,
  6,      4,    7
)

df %>% 
   group_by(state, ID) %>%
   summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop_last') %>% 
   summarise(count = mean(n), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Or it can be just

```
df %>%
    group_by(state, ID) %>%
    summarise(count = mean(service))
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is much better approach to get what I need.